# How to close a jframe with keyListener

Tags: jframe, dispose

I'm writing a simple slide program in java. In that program I want to show my slides like powerpoint in a new window.

I have main gui which has singleton pattern, hence, I am creating my SlideShowGUI in my MainGUI,

SlideShowGUI is very similar to this code, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BorderLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BorderLayoutDemo.java

I changed the createAndShowGUI() method with the following code, to remove title bar and maximize it like powerpoint slideshow mode

```
public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BorderLayoutDemo");
    frame.addKeyListener(key);
    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setUndecorated(true); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

In MainGUI I have buttons, and in ButtonHandler I execute this code:

```
ChakmaSystem.getInstance().getGui().getSlideShowGUI().createAndShowGUI();
```

Where ChakmaSystem.getInstance().getGui() returns the MainGUI, and getSlideShowGUI() is the getter method of the SlideShowGUI.

In SlideShowGUI, I added my own KeyListener, which keeps track of left right and escape buttons. Left and right work properly, however, I want escape button to close only my SlideShowGUI window.

To do that, in my keylistener I wrote the following codes:

```
// Escape Case
else if(keyCode == 27){
            ChakmaSystem.getInstance().getGui().getSlideShowGUI().dispose();
        }
```

I know that, when I press the escape it hits this case, however windows does not close.

What should I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just for people who are still looking for this - the way I close my programs is very, very simple:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
// Escape Case
else if(keyCode == 27){
            ChakmaSystem.getInstance().getGui().getSlideShowGUI().setVisile( false );
            ChakmaSystem.getInstance().getGui().getSlideShowGUI().dispose();
        }
```